# localstack unable to use aws secret with spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager, localstack

I am trying to load secret (and its values) in my local using localstack (docker-compose).

I am able to successfully start local stack and also able to create secret using below:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://127.0.0.1:4566 secretsmanager create-secret --name /secret/spring-boot-app --secret-string '{"username":"username","my_pwd":"password"}'
```

But when I am trying to access the value in Spring Boot App (Version 2.7.8, JDK 11), I am getting different errors (unable to resolve placeholders, secret manager cannot find secret etc).

Feel that getting mixed up with using the right dependencies and properties/configuration, to use secret that is sucessfully created in localstack.

Below is my application.yml

```
spring:
  config:
    import: aws-secretsmanager:/spring/spring-boot-app 

aws:
  secretsmanager:
    enabled: true
    endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:4566

cloud:
  aws:
    secretsmanager:
      endpoint: http://localhost:4566
    credentials:
      accessKey: dummy
      secretKey: dummy
      profile-name: dummy
    region:
      static: us-east-1
    stack:
      auto: true

test:
  value: ${my_pwd}
```

Basically it is unable to resolve the 'my_wd' or 'username' in any spring bean.

Tried different dependencies:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency> 
-----------------------or ------
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.398</version>
        </dependency>
```